# I am trying to create a list of set intersections in python

Tags: python, recursion, set

So give then sets `{'a', 'b', 'c'}`, `{'c', 'd'}`, `{'d','e','f'}`. I would like to get something like a list `[{'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'d'}, {'e','f'}]`. My first guess was that this would lend itself to recursion. set 1, set2 - set1, set3 - (set1 & set2). I think my experience with recursive functions is more along the factorial example which moves in the other direction. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the output needs to be? What is the origin of this problem? The intersection of these three sets is the empty set {}.

Comment: @TomRose the desired output is stated quite clearly in the question `[{'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'d'}, {'e','f'}]`

Comment: @agf It is a good question, but he did not: "Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work."  He just needs to edit it.

Comment: the result list doesn't correspond to `... (set1 & set2)`. You might mean `... (set1 | set2)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do this with recursion, but not necessary. It's straightforward to do it with iteration:

```
>>> sets = {'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'c', 'd'}, {'d','e','f'}
>>> unique = []
>>> seen = set()
>>> for s in sets:
...  unique.append(s - seen)
...  seen |= s
... 
>>> seen
set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'f'])
>>> unique
[set(['a', 'c', 'b']), set(['d']), set(['e', 'f'])]
```

Comment: explain that `|=` witchcraft plz

Comment: @Stephan http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.update

Answer (score 0):

I like python because of its list and set comprehensions.  I think this question highlights the convenience of this feature.

```
seta = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
setb = {'c', 'd'}
setc = {'d','e','f'}

list_of_sets = [seta, {b for b in setb: if b not in seta}, {c for c in setc: if c not in seta}]
```

Comment: This doesn't expand to more sets, which is what he's thinking about when he talks about recursion.